# How to perform Multilabel classification using spark ml in Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-ml, multilabel-classification

I have built a model that classifies emails based on keywords in subjects(features) into 10 different `work_categories` (labels). However, this task might consist of possibility where the emails should be categorized in more than a single label.

For example: A email with subject *"Servicing certificates and Transfer them"* should be classified into two labels i.e. `Servicing Worktype` (label 1) and `Transfer Worktype` (label 2). In my current program, this gets assigned to label `1` only. Is there anyway i can achieve classifying the email to both labels using spark ml in java ?

I have been following https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/ml for guidance, but there is nothing on multilabel classification.

Please, let me know if you have any suggestions or documentation that can help me on this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Both `LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS` and `LogisticRegressionWithSGD` support multi-label classification:

**[`LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/classification/LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS.html)**

> Train a classification model for Multinomial/Binary Logistic
>   Regression using Limited-memory BFGS. Standard feature scaling and L2
>   regularization are used by default.

or

**[`LogisticRegressionWithSGD`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/classification/LogisticRegressionWithSGD.html):**

> Train a classification model for Binary Logistic Regression using
>   Stochastic Gradient Descent. By default L2 regularization is used,
>   which can be changed via LogisticRegressionWithSGD.optimizer.
>
> **Using  `LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS` is recommended over this.**

Comment: But, I think these are only included in Spark mlib packages right. Do we have similar libaries for Sparl ML package ?